# How do I have mod_perl reload source files on change?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl

I am developing an application with mod`_`perl and restarting the server every time I change code is a huge drag.  I'd like to still use mod`_`perl for development because it's what I plan on using for the live server.  I didn't see anything in the documentation about how to do this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Apache2::Reload will somewhat accomplish what you're looking for.  However, remember to delete all this implementation once you're ready to put the app in production.

**Monitor All Modules in %INC**

To monitor and reload all modules in %INC at the beginning of request's processing, simply add the following configuration to your httpd.conf:

```
PerlModule Apache2::Reload
PerlInitHandler Apache2::Reload
```

When working with connection filters and protocol modules Apache2::Reload should be invoked in the pre_connection stage:

```
PerlPreConnectionHandler Apache2::Reload
```

**Register Modules Implicitly**

To only reload modules that have registered with Apache2::Reload, add the following to the httpd.conf:

```
PerlModule Apache2::Reload
PerlInitHandler Apache2::Reload
PerlSetVar ReloadAll Off
# ReloadAll defaults to On
```

Then any modules with the line:

```
use Apache2::Reload;
```

Will be reloaded when they change.

For for information check out [this documentation page](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/modperl/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/Reload.html).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution, from Perrin Harkins via PerlMonks:

> Set MaxRequestsPerChild to 1, then load any potentially-changing modules in the child, not the parent (obviously only for development environments). Each request will hit a fresh child server, which will load all of your potentially-changing modules anew.

From "[A better way to see module changes in a running web server](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=794860)"