# How do I have mod_perl reload source files on change?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl

I am using `mod_perl` for web development. I do not want to restart `mod_perl` every time I modify a Perl module.

I came across one solution that suggested using the `Apache::Reload` module and I installed this module from CPAN, modified `httpd.conf` accordingly and added `use Apache::Reload` to my Perl module, as stated in the documentation.

I tried the "reload all modules" method, and also one to reload a specific module when its file is touched, but both fail to work at all.

May I ask if anyone knows of any other `mod_perl` configuration (or any other factor) that could be preventing this from working?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442166/how-do-i-have-modperl-reload-source-files-on-change

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution, from Perrin Harkins via PerlMonks:

"Set MaxRequestsPerChild to 1, then load any potentially-changing modules in the *child*, not the parent (obviously only for development environments). Each request will hit a fresh child server, which will load all of your potentially-changing modules anew."

From "A better way to see module changes in a running web server" - http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=794860

Answer (score -1):

Consider writing your app using Plack, either directly or via one of the frameworks that have PSGI drivers. Then, when you're debugging, use the `plackup` tool like so:

```
$ plackup --server Apache2 -r --app /path/to/your_app.psgi
```

The plackup documentation has more details one how the `.psgi` file should look, and your framework's documentation should help too. Here's an example using Catalyst::Engine::PSGI

```
# app.psgi
use strict;
use MyApp;

MyApp->setup_engine('PSGI');
my $app = sub { MyApp->run(@_) };
```